# Handling a dropdown with submit button using Selenium on Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, dropdown

I'm really struggling to handle a dropdown and submit box via Selenium on ruby. I've got to this and tried a number of other options:

```
mySelect = browser.find_element(:id, "bulk_action")
option = mySelect.find_element(:css, "option[value='Accepted']")
```

Response:

```
[remote server] file:///var/folders/tt/pbz121011d1fvj5xmbyg78y00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20151012-46016-5sf82y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"bulk_action"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/tt/pbz121011d1fvj5xmbyg78y00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20151012-46016-5sf82y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement'
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/tt/pbz121011d1fvj5xmbyg78y00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20151012-46016-5sf82y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/tt/pbz121011d1fvj5xmbyg78y00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20151012-46016-5sf82y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
from [remote server] file:///var/folders/tt/pbz121011d1fvj5xmbyg78y00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20151012-46016-5sf82y/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:664:in `raw_execute'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:642:in `execute'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:611:in `find_element_by'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:61:in `find_element'
from mass_assign.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

[image: Source code for the page]

Any thoughts on how I can select the option then submit via the submit button?

Comment: Please post the HTML in the question instead of posting an image. At some point in the future, the image will no longer be available and this question will be less useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mass_accept = browser.find_element(id: 'bulk_action')
select_list = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(mass_accept)
select_list.select_by(:text, 'Accept')
dropdown_button = browser.find_element(:class, "button--primary")
dropdown_button.click
```

With massive thanks to http://elementalselenium.com/tips/5-select-from-a-dropdown

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and mark this as the answer. Thanks!